# Azure DevOps deployment fails with the error message "The operation was canceled."

Tags: deployment, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

My Azure DevOps pipeline tasks successfully complete without issues except for the final deployment step:

```
Job Issues - 1 Error
The job running on agent XXXX ran longer than the maximum time of 00:05:00 minutes. For more information, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2077134
```

The build logs state the operation was canceled:

```
021-03-02T20:50:00.4223027Z Folders: 695
2021-03-02T20:50:00.4223319Z Files: 10645
2021-03-02T20:50:00.4223589Z Size:       672611102
2021-03-02T20:50:00.4223851Z Compressed: 249144045
2021-03-02T20:50:03.6023001Z ##[warning]Unable to apply transformation for the given package. Verify the following.
2021-03-02T20:50:03.6032907Z ##[warning]1. Whether the Transformation is already applied for the MSBuild generated package during build. If yes, remove the <DependentUpon> tag for each config in the csproj file and rebuild. 
2021-03-02T20:50:03.6034584Z ##[warning]2. Ensure that the config file and transformation files are present in the same folder inside the package.
2021-03-02T20:50:04.5268038Z Initiated variable substitution in config file : C:\azagent\A2\_work\_temp\temp_web_package_3012195912183888\Areas\Admin\sitemap.config
2021-03-02T20:50:04.5552027Z Skipped Updating file: C:\azagent\A2\_work\_temp\temp_web_package_3012195912183888\Areas\Admin\sitemap.config
2021-03-02T20:50:04.5553082Z Initiated variable substitution in config file : C:\azagent\A2\_work\_temp\temp_web_package_3012195912183888\web.config
2021-03-02T20:50:04.5642868Z Skipped Updating file: C:\azagent\A2\_work\_temp\temp_web_package_3012195912183888\web.config
2021-03-02T20:50:04.5643366Z XML variable substitution applied successfully.
2021-03-02T20:51:00.8934630Z ##[error]The operation was canceled.
2021-03-02T20:51:00.8938641Z ##[section]Finishing: Deploy IIS Website/App:
```

When I examine the deployment states, I notice one of my tasks takes quite a while for what should be a fairly simple operation:

[image]

The file transform portion takes over half of the allotted 5 minutes?  Could this be the issue?

```
steps:
- task: FileTransform@1
  displayName: 'File Transform: '
  inputs:
    folderPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_site.com/drop/Release/Nop.Web.zip'
    fileType: json
    targetFiles: '**/dataSettings.json'
```

It may be inefficient but FileTransform log shows a significant amount of time spent after the variable has been substituted. Not sure what's causing the long delay, but the logs don't account for the time after the variable has been successfully substituted:

```
2021-03-02T23:04:44.3796910Z Folders: 695
2021-03-02T23:04:44.3797285Z Files: 10645
2021-03-02T23:04:44.3797619Z Size:       672611002
2021-03-02T23:04:44.3797916Z Compressed: 249143976
2021-03-02T23:04:44.3970596Z Applying JSON variable substitution for **/App_Data/dataSettings.json
2021-03-02T23:04:45.2396016Z Applying JSON variable substitution for C:\azagent\A2\_work\_temp\temp_web_package_0182869515217865\App_Data\dataSettings.json
2021-03-02T23:04:45.2399264Z Substituting value on key DataConnectionString with (string) value: ***
**2021-03-02T23:04:45.2446986Z JSON variable substitution applied successfully.
2021-03-02T23:07:25.4881687Z ##[section]Finishing: File Transform:**
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The job running on agent XXXX ran longer than the maximum time of 00:05:00 minutes.

Based on the error message, the cause of this issue is that the running time of the Agent Job has reached the maximum value set.

If you are using the release pipeline, you could set the timeout in `Agent Job -> Execution plan ->timeout`.

[image]

If you are using the build pipeline, you could set the timeout in `Agent Job -> Agent Job -> Execution plan -> timeout` (For An Agent Job) and `Options -> Build job -> Build job timeout in minutes` (For whole Build pipeline).

[image]

> The file transform portion takes over half of the allotted 5 minutes

From the task log, the zip package contains many files and folders. Therefore, transform task will take more time to traverse the file  to find the target file.

Comment: Thanks. I initially had the timeout set in the Deploy task and not the parent task. There's lots of serious issues with Azure DevOps' user interface. A helpful description next to the Timeout field clarifying its relationship with the parent task would have helped tremendously.